# How to call and display DWG file on browser using simple PHP code

Tags: php, dwg

I need help that how to call a DWG i.e. Autocad file in browser, and how to display it in browser using simple PHP code or any other solution but i want to display it using PHP only.

Comment: i am aslo facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

I was a CAD Manager for years and ran across this problem a lot. A .dwg file directly onto the net is difficult to do. There is some html out there that works decently; without writing an industrial strength application like a viewer, there is really little you can do. A .dwg file from Autodesk is ultra proprietary and therefore difficult to tame. There are open dwg standards that have been in development, but to the best of my knowledge, nothing exists for what you're looking for.

If you do find something or someone else knows about something, please leave it in the comments.